# URL formatting in Java

Tags: java

```
String arg="http://www.example.com/user.php?id=<URLRequest Method='GetByUID' />";
java.net.URI uri = new java.net.URI( arg );
java.awt.Desktop desktop = java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop();
desktop.browse( uri );
```

I want to open the given link in default browser with the above code but it says the url is invalid...i tried escaping characters like ' also but its not working.
If i replace String arg="www.google.com"; then there is no problem and I am able to open google.com. 
Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your string contains characters that aren't valid in a URI, per [RFC 2396](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt). You need to properly encode the query parameters. Many utilities support that, like the standard [URLEncoder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) (lower level), [JAX-RS UriBuilder](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder.html), [Spring UriUtils](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriUtils.html), Apache HttpClient [URLEncodedUtils](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/utils/URLEncodedUtils.html) and so on.

**Edit:** Oh, and the URI class can handle it, too, but you have to use a [different constructor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URI.html#constructor_summary):

```
URI uri = new URI("http", "foo.com", null, "a=<some garbage>&b= |{$0m3 m0r3 garbage}| &c=imokay", null);
System.out.println(uri);
```

Outputs:

```
http://foo.com?a=%3Csome%20garbage%3E&b=%20%7C%7B$0m3%20m0r3%20garbage%7D%7C%20&c=imokay
```

which, while ugly, is the correct representation.

Answer (score 2):

Thats because it *is* invalid. `<URLRequest Method='GetByUID' />` should be replaced by the value of the `id`, or an expression that returns the `id` which you can concatenate with the `arg` string. Something like

`String arg="http://www.example.com/user.php?id="+getByUID(someUid);`

Comment: no i actually want it that way only http://www.example.com/user.php?id=<URLRequest Method='GetByUID' />.........is there any way to do that?

Comment: @lbrt Try to escape all the non-text chars.

Comment: @lbrt I don't see how that could be; I'd need to see the encoded output to believe that--see Andrew's answer.

Comment: @DaveNewton: He probably encoded the whole URI, which would incorrectly replace the :, /, ?, and =.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

class ARealURL {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String s1 = "http://www.example.com/user.php?id=";
        String param = "<URLRequest Method='GetByUID' />";
        String encodedParam = URLEncoder.encode(param,"UTF-8");

        URL url = new URL(s1+encodedParam);
        System.out.println(url);
    }
}
```

### Output

```
http://www.example.com/user.php?id=%3CURLRequest+Method%3D%27GetByUID%27+%2F%3E
```

Comment: This encodes spaces as `+`. What if I want spaces encoded as `%20` ?